# this.$children is behaving as if it were reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

The official [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children) says the `this.$children` is not reactive,

> The direct child components of the current instance. Note there’s no order guarantee for $children, and it is not reactive...

hence, any changes should not trigger any re-renders. [`this.$children` api is removed from vuejs v3, hence it works only in `v2.x`.]

I found this interesting... https://codepen.io/tatimblin/pen/oWKdjR

The code in sandbox above is a demonstration of tab UI implemented using `slot` & `this.$childen` api.
Initially `tabs` component is holding a reference to the `this.$children` Array, here's a log of that:

[image: this.$children]

Interesting part is, the `isActive` prop of `tab` is being changed using that Array, yet it's reflected in each component, resulting in re-render..
I'm not sure what's happening here.. maybe I'm missing something.

template:

```
<div id="root" class="container">

  <tabs>
    <tab name="Services" :selected="true">
      <h1>What we do</h1>
    </tab>
    <tab name="Pricing">
      <h1>How much we do it for</h1>
    </tab>
    <tab name="About Us">
      <h1>Why we do it</h1>
    </tab>
  </tabs>

</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('tabs', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <div class="tabs">
              <ul>
                <li v-for="tab in tabs" :class="{ 'is-active': tab.isActive }">
                    <a :href="tab.href" @click="selectTab(tab)">{{ tab.name }}</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="tabs-details">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    
    data() {
        return {tabs: [] };
    },
    
    created() {
        
        this.tabs = this.$children;
        
    },
    methods: {
        selectTab(selectedTab) {
            this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
                tab.isActive = (tab.name == selectedTab.name); 
               // this is how the isActive prop is changed, using this.$children
            });
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('tab', {
    
    template: `

        <div v-show="isActive"><slot></slot></div>

    `,
    
    props: {
        name: { required: true },
        selected: { default: false}
    },
    
    data() {
        
        return {
            isActive: false
        };
        
    },
    
    computed: {
        
        href() {
            return '#' + this.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
        }
    },
    
    mounted() {
        
        this.isActive = this.selected;
        
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#root'
});
```

Comment: "the name prop of `tab` is being changed using that Array".  Where?  The only thing setting tab `name` prop is the template

Comment: @Dan my bad.. I mean the `isActive` porp.., I've already mention correctly in the comment where the prop is being changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The children are reactive because they are Vue components themselves, having the full power of reactivity already, apart from the `tabs` parent.

The doc quote means content that would otherwise not be reactive on its own.  This distinction could maybe be a little clearer.  On the other hand, `tabs` would not work properly if the slot content was anything other than a component with an `isActive` property, which forms a tight coupling.  It wouldn't work properly with raw HTML slot content such as:

```html
  <tabs>
    <div>
      Hi, I'm not a component
    </div>
  </tabs>
```

Comment: thank you.. actually the vue components referenced in the `this.$children` which are indeed reactive.. not the `this.$children` itself, I understand now..

Comment: how can I get the vue component rendered inside `slot` in vuejs v3?

Comment: You can use `this.$slots.default()`

Comment: I've tried.. values return by the `default()` method aren't `vue component`s, they're something else.. and is indeed not reactive..

Comment: They're VNodes, and they are reactive, but you can't reach down from the parent and grab their data.  However, this is a bit of a hack with `this.$children` anyway, which might be why they removed the capability (violation of [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)).